# Identificar diferenças entre dois projetos similares

Tags: php, git

Tenho dois projetos em PHP: um é uma loja do Rio, e outro é a loja de São Paulo. Basicamente, o de SP está na raiz, e o do Rio é "quase" que um clone do projeto de SP. Cada projeto é apresentado de uma maneira, o do rio está sendo carregado numa subpasta **rio** que é carregado no domínio, e o outro pega direto da raiz do site. (fiz essa dinâmica, usando um comando do linux, para apontar o projeto através de um link simbólico:
`[user@maquina projeto]/loja-SP/ (master)$  ln -s ../loja-RJ/ rio`)

para exemplificar melhor, os projetos são acessados assim:

> /loja-RJ/ (master) -->  www.lojaxyz.com.br/rio
>   /loja-SP/ (master) --> www.lojaxyz.com.br/

Gostaria de compará-los para ver as divergências, para tratar um erro que está ocorrendo somente no do rio. Mas cada um está num repositório do Git diferente. Gostaria de algo assim:

exemplo fictício: `git /loja-RJ/ diff ../loja-SP/ name-only--`

Comment: Precisa ser com o Git? Isso parece trabalho para uma ferramenta de _diff_.

Comment: Não precisa, só quero ver a diferença entre alguns arquivos de ambos os projetos, é possível, sem ter que pegar arquivo por arquivo? Uso a IDE PHPStorm. E estou tendo que revisar arquivo por arquivo com o "Compare With Clipboard". Só que é muito arquivo... além de controllers, classes, overrides, templates, helpers...

Comment: Estou vendo agora,  se [esta seria essa a solução](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/comparing-folders.html).

Comment: Aparentemente, a solução acima resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Faça uma resposta detalhando como foi o processo. Isso pode ajudar quem mais tiver esse problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver o problema, utilizando o PHP Storm [segui este tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/comparing-folders.html), dentro do projeto, cliquei em CTRL + D, e na janela que abriu, selecionei os diretórios dos dois projetos, colocando cada um lado a lado, onde ele comparou na janela os arquivos iguais, que não haviam em ambos os projetos e os que foram modificados. Conforme está na imagem do tutorial:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem dois repositórios git, em dois locais diferentes, e precisa saber se existem diferenças entre eles, você pode rodar um `git diff` entre ambos, pra ver as diferenças (se existirem, claro).

Levando em conta que você tem um `repositorio_a`, e quer comparar ele com um `repositorio_b`, faça o seguinte no `repositorio_a`:

```
# Vá até o repositorio_a
cd /home/usuario/repositorio_a

# Adicione o repositorio_b como um remote
git remote add -f b /home/usuario/repositorio_b

# Veja as diferenças
git diff master remotes/b/master

# Quando estiver satisfeito, remova o remote
git remote rm b
```